# Android + Is there any Limit to Activities Or XML files?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, limit

I have the following requirement:

-----> Showing Five elements of different color and Allow user to select the correct one.

-----> Like that I want to show 16 Kinds(Means 16*5 = 80 elements on 16 Activities)in Random.

===> For that I have created 16 activities and corresponding 16 XML files, and used them Randomly.

&&

First I'l show 5 colors and let the user select one(Say Green), If it is correct, I'l let him select one from another set of 5 colors(This time red)....& so on...Like that I have to make him choose 16 Colors Randomly.And repeat this 16 random colors until he press Back button.That' the exact flow

By the End of the Day, I am in Small Dilemma that, May be there , will be some kind of Logic that winds up the work bit smoothly By reducing the code.

If yes ,Tell me the Logic .

I have all the 80 different elements , to show them in 16 activities, 5 per Activity.

Answer (score 1):

If the elements are the same type, you can have one Activity instead of 16 and choose what to show when creating Activity(or even use Fragments for that). 
Any way, you have to be more specific in your question if you want to get complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating 16 different activities, You can create a single activity and 16 different layouts. You can change the layout of activity dynamically and I think it would be good, avoid creating so many activity if there is really no need of it.

Comment: tell me the flow of your application in detail

Comment: In my application , If click a button on main screen,Next I want to show this colors.That means First I'l show 5 colors and let the user select one(Say Green), If it is correct, I'l let him select one from another set of 5 colors(This time red)....& so on...Like that I have to make him choose 16 Colors Randomly.And repeat this 16 random colors until he press Back button.That' the exact flow....

Comment: @sai `if(.....){
setContentView(R.layout.blabla)} else{ setContentView(R.layout.blabla1)}
`